# Build a pyramid in a minecraft bukkit plugin

Tags: java, geometry, minecraft, bukkit

I want to build a simple pyramid in Minecraft using a method in a bukkit-plugin. The final result shall look like this:[image]

I wrote this code:

```
public static void buildPyramid(Location l) {
    Location pos;
    for(int i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
        for(int j = -2; j <= 2; j++) {
            pos = l.clone().add(i, 0, j);
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) + ""); // for test
            int diff = Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j);
            switch(diff) {
                case 2:
                    l.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    l.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, 1, 0);
                    l.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, -1, 0);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    l.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, 1, 0);
                    l.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, 1, 0);
                    l.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, -2, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly, what happens is that one bedrock is placed on Location l and nothing else happens.
It is quite dispairing... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, the solution is that simple. I used the wrong variable:

```
public static void buildPyramid(Location l) {
    Location pos;
    for(int i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
        for(int j = -2; j <= 2; j++) {
            pos = l.clone().add(i, 0, j);
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) + ""); // for test
            int diff = Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j);
            switch(diff) {
                case 2:
                    pos.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    pos.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, 1, 0);
                    pos.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, -1, 0);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    pos.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, 1, 0);
                    pos.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, 1, 0);
                    pos.getBlock().setType(Material.BEDROCK);
                    pos.add(0, -2, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
        for(int j = -2; j <= 2; j++) {
            pos = l.clone().add(i, 0, j);
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j) + ""); // for test
            int diff = Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j);
```

the first approach to body varibles' situations are: i = -2 and j = -2. After this line' execution:

```
int diff = Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(j);
```

they will be i = -2 and j = -2 but diff = 4 because `Math.abs()` method convert -2 to 2 for both variables then sums them for diff. As a result of this, your `switch-case` statment will not work properly. By the way i recommend you to calculate all things again from start.